# Write Excel file from Outlook Emails

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, outlook, excel-2010

I have written some code in Python that reads through emails in an Outlook folder using win32com.client. I can read it in easily, have all of the logic built out, now want to write an Excel file as I iterate through all of the messages. This is where I have a problem.

My latest attempt used xlwt but I am open to using anything. The problem I am running into is that when I try to write a cell with the Sender or the Date from the outlook email, I get the following error:

> Exception: Unexpected data type

Does anyone know how I can fix this/get around it?

Do I have to convert the .Sender, .Date instances to some other form?

Quick sample below:

```
import win32com.client
import xlwt
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet = book.add_sheet("New Sheet")
for folder in inbox_folders:
    fold = folder.Items
    for messages in fold:
        date = fold.ReceivedTime
        sender = fold.Sender
        sheet.write(1,0,date)
        sheet.write(2,0,sender)
```

Comment: Do you have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that you'd be willing to post? It would improve your post so that other might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I added a quick sample of something that would be similar to what I am trying to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an alternative to xlwt, you may want to consider openpyxl also: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `sheet.write(2,0,sender)` with `sheet.write(2,0,sender.Name)` or `sheet.write(2,0,sender.Address).`

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can have objects other than MailItem in the Inbox folder, such as MeetingItem or ReportItem which do not expose the Sender and ReceivedTime properties. Check that the Class property =  43.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, the sender.Name works perfectly! Do you know what I can use to get the date to fill in correctly? And thats a great point about the objects - the folder I am using is only mailitems but definitely something to keep in mind. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the problem with the date?

Comment: It gives the same error but I found a way around it with sheet.write(2,0,str(date)) and that seems to work. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: What is the type of the sheet variable?

Comment: it was an instance just as the sender was

Comment: Yes, but an instance of what object? I don't think the Worksheet object in the Excel Object Model exposes the write() method.

Comment: I have 3 outlook profiles (3 different email accounts) setup. So how to choose which profile's (account's) Inbox to use?

Comment: @user5155835 - start a new thread. Do not hijack an existing thread that has nothing to do with your question